# Strange light effect in EEVEE render

Tags: shaders, lighting, eevee-render-engine

While making my bedroom scene, I have this lighting artifact that I cant seem to get rid of on my area light. Its like little lines of light that separate and get further apart as it diffuses. Here's what it looks like.[image: Light Problem]

The lights power setting seems to have no effect on the lines nor does its size or position. My softness doesn't do anything either. Here is a picture of my lights settings.[image: Light settings]

Could it be a problem with my EEVEE settings? It still occurs even after baking lighting. Here is a picture of the problem with my EEVEE settings also included.
[image: Problem in baked lighting and settings]
 Let me know if there is anything else I should include that could help come up with an answer.

Comment: that happens because the EEVEE renderer is not perfect with shadows because it is a real time renderer so it needs to take "shortcuts" now and then, the cycles renderer is more photo-realistic but isn't a real time renderer so it's harder on the computer so it probebly will not have that artifact

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that its less noticeable? Does it go away in the final render? Thanks